# TotalMTD is not showing blank for categories which does not have any value for current month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In a Power BI visual, I have two columns: "BDDs" and "Month-to-Date Revenue." Some values in the "Month-to-Date Revenue" column are displaying incorrectly as values instead of 0 (These are highlighted in a Red box in below screenshot. It's showing values from previous month i.e. December 2022 instead of current month i.e. February 2023. There's no sale in January 2023?).

To ensure that these values appear as 0, what should I do?

I noticed that, the total value is displayed correctly and does not take into account the incorrect values that are showing (Red box). I am using the following measure for the "Month-to-Date Revenue":

```
Month-to-Date Revenue = TOTALMTD(SUM([Opportunities][Direct Contract Value (Base)]), [Opportunities][Actual Close Date])
```

[Click here for the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3Vta.png)

I found an article here but I'm not sure on how to implement this. Here's the article link: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/TotalMTD-is-not-showing-blank-for-categories-which-does-not-have/m-p/427346#M196737

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding + 0 to the measure as under:

```
Month-to-Date Revenue = TOTALMTD(SUM([Opportunities][Direct Contract Value (Base)]), [Opportunities][Actual Close Date]) + 0
```

Prior to that, all null values of the column [Direct Contract Value (Base)] were set to 0.